# Using low level datatype from hardware abstraction layer in (high level) application

Tags: c++, c, architecture, abstraction-layer

I have a hardware abstraction layer for a peripheral of a MCU which is written in C. The application code is using the peripheral via a C++ wrapper. Now I have a low level enum `ll_enum` and a function, that requires a parameter with this datatype.

My understanding of a good architecture would imply the following things:

- Low-level peripheral driver (C)

  - should not know that there is a higher level
  - has the definition of the enum
- C++ Wrapper

  - obviously knows the low-level layer and that there is an application
- Application Code that uses the C++ Wrapper

  - Just knows the C++ Wrapper

My solution right now:

I have a enum in the C++ Wrapper that has the same entries as the low level enum. The enum gets casted to the low level type in the C++ Wrapper.

```
// ### C++ Wrapper ###
enum hl_enum {
    foo = 1,
    bar = 2,
}

void Peripheral::hl_function(hl_enum param) {
    ll_function((ll_enum)param);
}

// ### Low level C-file ###
typedef enum {
    foo = 1,
    bar = 2,
} ll_enum;

void ll_function(ll_enum param);
```

Obviously that is a bad solution, because you have to change code at two positions and get in trouble if you missed that.

Is there a better solution?